# Unable to set Hebrew Keyboard on android lockscreen for unlock phone?

Tags: android, lockscreen

So extending reference to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182362/settings-non-english-language-password-on-android-phone). Now i am able to set Hebrew password on my android based Motorola phone. After setting this password hebrew based, i wanted to unlock the same using "Choose input method" and selecting Hebrew but phone does not shown me the key pad to do so even after selecting hebrew. Attaching screen shot

1. Setting system language to English US and trying to choose input method for hebrew and unlocking password but unable to get hebrew key pad. [image]
2. Setting system language to Hebrew and choose input method for hebrew and unlocking password but unable to get hebrew key pad[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally got answer to my own question :

Move to **framework/base/packages/keyguard/res/layout**
And modify **keyguard_password_view.xml** node EditText by removing/commenting `android:imeOptions="flagForceAscii|actionDone"`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/passwordEntry"
                 android:layout_width="0dip"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyguard_lockscreen_pin_margin_left"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:textStyle="normal"
                 android:inputType="textPassword"
                 android:textSize="36sp"
                 android:background="@null"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                 android:textColor="#ffffffff"
               <!--android:imeOptions="flagForceAscii|actionDone" -->
           />
```

And now it will allow non-ASCII keypad to be launched.